# Как не потерять кэширование 1-го уровня Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

Кэш 1-го уровня у *Hibernate* храниться в сессии, и с ее закрытием теряются и все данные которые в нем были. Встает вопрос: как задизайнить свой `DAO` слой что-бы не потерять это полезное свойство *Hibernate*? Получается что надо держать сессию открытой? Но когда-то же надо ее закрывать...

На пример вот такой DAO класс:

```
public class DAOImpl implements DAO {

    private final SessionFactory factory;

    public DAOImpl(final SessionFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void addUser(final User user) {

        try (final Session session = factory.openSession()) {

            session.beginTransaction();

            session.save(user);

            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
    }
    //... и остальные CRUD операции.
}
```

Тут вероятно воспользоваться преимеществами кеширования не получится. Каждый кто придет откроет новую сессию и закроет ее при выходе из метода.

Объясните пожалуйста на примере этого небольшого класса как сделать так, что-бы преимущества кэширования были использованы (для начала хоть как-то), но при этом и проблемы с брошенной не закрытой сессией тоже не было? Как в обычных типовых случаях такое решается? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать кэш 2го уровня - он распространяется на фабрику сессий: при открытии очередной сессии `factory.openSession()` она "будет видеть изменения предыдущих сессиий" этой фабрики (у них будет общий кэш).
По умолчанию кэш 2го уровня выключен. Для включения необходимо указать:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider"/>
    //или  в более старых версиях
    //<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
```

1я строка указывает на конкретную реализацию кэша, популярные варианты:

- EHCache
- OSCache
- SwarmCache
- JBoss TreeCache

Подробнее:
[оф. документация](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-cache), [статья на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/135176/%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80)